# Keep aspect ration based on height

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

here is the problem i have. I want to keep the aspect ratio of a photo and fit it into an landscape div. The problem is that i want to fit picture on height and make crop on width. Here is the script i use to fit pic but it fits on width instead height.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.story-small img').each(function() {
        var maxWidth = 550; // Max width for the image
        var maxHeight = 413;    // Max height for the image
        var ratio = 0;  // Used for aspect ratio
        var width = $(this).width();    // Current image width
        var height = $(this).height();  // Current image height

        // Check if the current width is larger than the max
        if(width > maxWidth){
            ratio = maxWidth / width;   // get ratio for scaling image
            $(this).css("width", maxWidth); // Set new width
            $(this).css("height", height * ratio);  // Scale height based on ratio
            height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
            width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
        }

        // Check if current height is larger than max
        if(height > maxHeight){
            ratio = maxHeight / height; // get ratio for scaling image
            $(this).css("height", maxHeight);   // Set new height
            $(this).css("width", width * ratio);    // Scale width based on ratio
            width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

here is an example: [Link](http://websoftit.ro/dragdrop/)

so practicly second pic is good cause it fits on height, that's what i want to achiev for landscape pics, fit on height crop width.
Thnx in advance.

Comment: You can probably do this with just css, no script, though I dont understand exactly what you are trying to achieve. you want to keep the image height, and crop its width to fit the div width?  can you show a screenshot example of the effect?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rM5aU/)

CSS:

```
img{
max-width: 550px;
max-height:440px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="http://websoftit.ro/dragdrop/emma-watson-wallpaper-1920x1200.jpg">
```